# How to deploy a WAR file which is located in zip file(window) to linux

Tags: bash

Right now my situation is like this. I created a war file using eclipse in window. Now i want to zip my war file together with my bash script so that automate installation will occur. Is it anyway so that my bash script can automatically recognize my war file?

Comment: Are all war files in same location ??

Answer (score 0):

You could easily use the `zip` command. See `man zip` for more details.

If you want to archive multiples war files in the same directory :

```
lstPath=""
for warFile in "$DIR"/*.zip; do
    lstPath="$lstPath $warFile"
done
zip a.zip lstPath
```

Or :

```
lstPath=""
for warFile in "$DIR"/*.zip; do
    zip a.zip "$warFile"
done
```

And if the war files are not in the same directory, you could use the `find` command ;)